# Cannot INSERT into database on a shared server

Tags: mysql, permissions, php

I have launched an application on a shared server but I cannot `INSERT` any data. I thought maybe I don't have privileges so I did `SHOW GRANTS` in my application then `die()`

The result was **[ EDITED ]**:

```
  [Grants for gigfa_11863212@%] => GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES ON `gigfa_11863212_life_journal`.* TO 'gigfa_11863212'@'%'
  [Grants for gigfa_11863212@%] => GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'gigfa_11863212'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*78839FD7FF9639FB72CCB5E9D8BCD81A7A0A9E3D' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 80000 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 60000 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 20000
```

Why do I get the following error message when I issue an INSERT statement?

*< INSERT command denied to user 'user'@'host' for table 'table' >*

Comment: When you connect to the database, please run the following query: `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and tell us the output of this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally stupid ...

I my entire project which designed and developed locally and code-line's count reaches about 15000 lines, I just mentioned my local database JUST one time in my entire project! and see the result of that!!! I have been down for this about 24 hours!

Thank you all guys for trying to help

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have granted usage to user@% but all other things to usr@%.

Comment: i just replaced my actual *user_name* and *host_name* with **usr** .. the one you saw was just a missed-type! :)

Comment: Miss-type? Copy+Paste will prevent that. :)

Comment: add the exact result of `SHOW GRANTS` when logged in with that user.  Also include the *exact* insert command and error message.  We need to be able to confirm you're doing what you think you are.

Comment: @Gavin: To show EXACT result of `SHOW GRANTS` the main question is edited. To show the EXACT `INSERT` command, right now i don't have access to my codes! i post them ASAP

Comment: Are you connecting from localhost or another host?

Comment: @Gavin: your comment made me to look at a code which overlooked for 100 times but never happened to see the failure code! Thank You